# Visual Studio project folder conventions

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

A few versions back, Visual Studio started using *C:\Users\Jonathan\source\repos* as the default project folder (instead of *C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects*). I prefer the old location under *Documents*, but I decided to just accept the newer location because I figure that is more likely to avoid conflicts, avoid having to change it with each new release and just generally the path of least resistance moving forward.

Now I want to create a GitHub repository. But the default *Local path* is the *same* path where the project is stored! So without changing this path, I get the following error:

> Repository with same name already exists at this location.

Obviously, I can change this path. But I'm trying to go with Microsoft's recommended folder locations to avoid conflicts. And so it seems ironic that I've run into a conflict using these locations!

Questions:

1. Does anyone know why Visual Studio needs a local repository path in addition to the current project folder?
2. Does anyone know why Visual Studio is defaulting to the same path for both? What is the intended convention for these locations?

Comment: And if you close Visual Studio, `git init` your solution folder directly from the command line, reopen Visual Studio, what then?

Comment: IMHO, you should provide some repro steps. I don't see the same things as you do.

Comment: I think it defaults when you select the git integration with Visual Studio to that directory during installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git needs a local repo. VS is trying to create a local repo, but you want to use the existing repo.

How do I do ?

```
File => Add to Source Control
View =>  Team Explorer
Sync
```

It will not ask to create a new repository.

Did I answer your question ?

You are dealing with "git clone" and git clone only works with an empty folder then its ok if it defaults to the projects folder, lets [clone](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/cloning-a-repository-to-visual-studio.md) the project.

If you already have the project in your computer and just want to [push](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/publishing-an-existing-project-to-github.md) the code, then you should init your local git repo in the project folder, add the github remote and push the code into the remote repository.

Here you have some [docs](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/tree/master/docs/using).

Answer (score 2):

VS has default project location: Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Locations:

[image]

and default location for git repos: Team Explorer -> Settings -> Git -> Global Settings:

[image]

and they should be the same because project and local repo should be in the same folder.

But you can change them what I did. You don't need to follow default MS recommendations, just select folder convenient for you.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56386670/240564) is correct. Just select your Solution, right click and press **Add Solution to source control...**

Comment: Thanks, but I pointed out in the question that I could change the defaults, and went on to explain why I might want to keep them.

Comment: I don't see reason to keep them. And why changing them can cause conflicts. Of course you can keep them, just need to understand why there are 2 options and why they should be the same.

Comment: It's just a preference about the default clone folder and the default project folder. If you want external cloned projects in the same folder as your original created projects then set them to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual studio 2017 community edition.
I ended up doing this.

**For new projects**

- when creating a new project check "Create new Git repository" option
- create Github empty repository
- push from local repository to Github as remote using empty repository
  link

**for other projects**

- clone empty github repository to folder
- add project files
- push to github